# Android scan package in apk for files

Tags: java, android

I have the code to scan a given directory in a system.  But I have a package inside my app, which I want to scan for classes that are in that package.

So my directory structure looks like this:

```
APK:
    -Package x:
        -x.class
        -y.class
    -Package z:
        -a.class
        -b.class
        -c.class
```

So inside Package x, in x.class I want to scan Package z for all the files in there.  This will allow me to dynamically add classes to Package z and then I can access them from my x.class.

I've tried relative paths from within the apk and absolute paths as well, both resulted in a null pointer.

If you need any clarification please ask.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm sort of an idiot and realized I can do this really easily by import the entire package z.  From there I can just set an array of all the class names.  It's not as simple or elegant that I would want.  But it will solve my problem.

I will still look for a way to scan package z in my apk, but this will get me started.